# Computing oriented Bordism groups of a manifold $X$ for $n\leq 4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, cobordism

I'm following the book of Davis and Kirk "Lecture notes in Algebraic Topology" where, at pages $246-247$ there is a computation of the aforementioned groups via the Atiyah- Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence.

Using the well-known fact that $\Omega^{SO}_k(*)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ for $k= 0,4$, and it is trivial for $k=1,2,3$ together with the split injevtiveness of the edge homomorphism it's easy to conclude that for  $n\leq 3$, $\Omega^{SO}_n(X)\cong H_n(X)$.

I'm interested in computing the $4$th Group, since in this degree there is a possible non-trivial extension problem. At the stable page, in position $(0,4)$ there is $\mathbb{Z}$, in position $(4,0)$ there is $H_4(X)$. If the position of these two groups were exchanged, by the projectivity of $\mathbb{Z}$ (as an abelian Group) the extension problem would be trivial. But in this case, since it is not injective I dont know how to deal with the Short exact sequence.

According to the reference it should be a trivial extension problem, i.e. $\Omega^{SO}(X)_4\cong H_4(X)\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ but they dont give any reason for it.

Can someone provide some explanations for this?

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: I wrote manifold in the title, I dont want to assume more hypothesis on it.

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure if it was something more specific in the notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that we have an exact sequence $0 \to \Bbb Z \to \Omega^{SO}_4(X) \to H_4(X) \to 0$. Here are a couple of ways we can show this sequence splits.

1) Identify the first map as $\Omega^{SO}_4(pt) \to \Omega_4^{SO}(X)$ for some choice of basepoint. Then there is an obvious splitting given by retracting to that basepoint. I suspect this is the solution they intended, since they note above your result that $\Omega_n(pt) \to \Omega_n(X)$ is a split injection for any $X$.

2) The right map is the map that forgets the manifold defining it. You can get an inverse to it by picking a choice of manifold representing it of signature 0. (This is sorta cheating, since I would only think of it if I already knew what the first map was.)

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for the answer. Could you please give me some hints about how to show that the first map is the inclusion of the point? Is it a consequence of the construction of the AHSS? There are some tricks about how to identity it?

Comment: @Riccardo The filtration of $h^4(X)$ is by its $n$-skeletons. The first term is $F^0h^4(X) = h^4(pt)$, and the map is inclusion. Further filtrations chainge nothing until $F^4h^4(X) = h^4(X)$. The last map is $h^4(X)/h^4(pt)$.

Comment: Dear Mike, sorry for commenting again an accepted answer, but as I went on with my computations, I'm rather interested in the second part of the answer you wrote. Do you know any reference for it? I'm convinced that the first map $\mathbb{Z}\to MSO_4(X)$ would be the signature. If I understood what you are claiming, the map would associate to each equiv. class $x$ of cycles in $H_4(X)$ a singular 4-manifold with signature 0 $(M,f)$, s.t. $f_*[M]=x$. Is that correct? how can I see that it's indeed possible?

Comment: @Riccardo I'm afraid if I ever had an idea about how to do that, I've lost it this past week. I know how to obtain a right inverse on the level of sets - first, find a manifold representing the cycle (essentially, represent the cycle as a simplicial complex, and surger out neighborhoods of singularities... try doing this in 2 and 3 dimensions for a picture of how to start - this is Rene Thom's approach to the problem of representing homology classes by submanifolds); if it's not signature 0, connect sum on some $\Bbb{CP}^2$s (with appropriate orientation) that map to a point until it does.

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks a lot for your insight anyway. I think I managed to find a solution to this problem by noticing that the edge homomorphism in the AHSS is exactly the map $MSO_4(X)\to H_4(X)$ s.t. $(M,f)\mapsto f_*[M]$, therefore one can prove clearly that it's surjective and that the kernel is $F_0MSO_4(X)=MSO_4(\ast)$. Thanks again, without your comments I wouldn't have been able to go through this